# Neo4j: Starting Neo4j too slow and go failed

Tags: neo4j

I have a strange issue when starting `neo4j`:

[image]

After start neo4j with `sudo service neo4j start`, I check status using `sudo service neo4j status`, it notices that `Starting Neo4j`. This process is too slow and go failed after

[image]

I've completed configurations in `neo4j.conf` file before and allow all needed ports in `firewall`.

[image]

Logging by `./neo4j.log`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be neo4j running under linux. 
Can you run this command and post the neo4j.log here?
This might give some clue on what is going on.

journalctl -u neo4j -b > ./neo4j.log

Comment: Can you verify the following?
-All the folders pointed by the neo4j.conf. See if the folders exist, if they have the right permissions (i believe they need to be owned by user neo4j. )

Comment: Can you also verify The jvm version used by neo4j (is it java 8, or greater?)

Comment: - All the folders pointed by the `neo4j.conf` already and have permission.
- JVM: `java -version`: `openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)`, $JAVA_HOME path set.

Comment: Others in the past had this error due to mismatch in java version. And neo4j 4.0 series needs Java 11. If you are using neo4j 4.0, you may want to try removing java8 and try with java 11.  <br/>

Another setting to try is to change the logging level to debug and restart neo4j. The setting is, dbms.logs.debug.level=INFO in neo4j.conf. Change that to DEBUG. See new neo4j.log and debug.log have any other useful info.

Comment: @blackrain Your current answer should really have been a comment. Please update your answer so that it provides useful information. Perhaps you can restate the information from the above comments.

Comment: Adding my answer as a comment. SO wouldn't let me add a comment before i answered for some reason. 
This seems to be neo4j running under linux. Can you run this command and post the neo4j.log here? This might give some clue on what is going on.

journalctl -u neo4j -b > ./neo4j.log

Comment: OK, since you do not have enough [reputation points to add a comment to someone else's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), adding a redundant comment to your own "answer" does not make sense. Please ignore my prior comment. :-)